Equation labels increase the counter in LaTeX amsmath
I couldn't find a thread that has this issue (though related ones that where distinct in some point and did not help):
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

    \usepackage{a4wide}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{floatflt}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{placeins}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    %\usepackage{accents}
    \usepackage[labelfont={sf},font={sf}]{caption}
    \usepackage{aliascnt}
    \usepackage{sidecap}
    \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
    
    \newaliascnt{eqfloat}{equation}
    \newfloat{eqfloat}{h}{eqflts}
    \floatname{eqfloat}{Equation}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{mwe}
        \begin{eqfloat}
            \begin{equation}
                \partial v=\frac{\gamma -1}{\gamma^3*\beta^3}*\partial E
            \end{equation}
            \caption{Relative velocity spread calculated relativistically}
            \label{eq:velocity_spread}
        \end{eqfloat}
\end{document}


is typesetting as

Why is the counter of Equations increasing by one for the caption here (and also for all subsequent equations)? Would be really glad if someone could help me(mind I am inexperienced and stupid). :)
lg
PS: used global commands

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

As long as we do not have code that can be copied as is that replicate the issue, there is not much we can do. It is well known that amsmath typeset its contents twice. And "strange" manual code need to take this into account.

Why are you floating equation? That seems like asking for trouble.

Code should work now, sry I messed up with the question mask

\caption usually increase the counter of the environment in which it is used. So a \caption inside a eqfloat does increase the eqfloat counter. And because you've declared the eqfloat counter to be an alias of the equation counter, increasing the eqfloat counter also increases the equation counter. So without a minimal working example I guess the result is expected.

I am floating  them because I hoped it improves visual appeal and they are not tied to a specific point in text. If needed I can remove float I think

Thanks @cabohah  Is there a trivial fix? \notag did not work

Have you seen the link in my comment?

Ok give me a minute

Off-topic: Package a4wide is not really recommended. See section 1.1 of Das LaTeX2e-Sündenregister or the translations.

ok, Sündenregister i will look at

Should work now

Don't think, that it works without \documentclass …

sry, forgot to paste documentclass. Thanks for your patience

Do you really need the number twice? Wouldn't it be enough to either use \[…\] instead of \begin{equation}…\end{equation} or use \caption*{…} instead of \caption{…} (or even remove the \caption{…})?. If you want a llist of equations, you can still use \addcontentsline{eqflts}{eqfloat}{…}.

\caption*{} might be fine. If it is complicated to work around double numbers I might settle with this idea.

Originally (and still considering) I wanted a list of equation and used captions for the required labels.

See egreg's answer for a solution, that uses the number twice without increasing it. But I would try to not not confuse the reader showing the same number several times. \label is already supported by equation (or align or other numbered equation environments).

I have to be afk now for 1-2 hours in a meeting. Thanks a lot so far for your patience @cabobah. I will look into later again.

You just need to define a suitable label format and use \theequation instead of the counter set up for eqfloat.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[labelfont={sf},font={sf}]{caption}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=eqflts,
  placement=htp,
  name=Equation,
]{eqfloat}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{useequation}{#1~\theequation}
\captionsetup[eqfloat]{labelformat=useequation}
\renewcommand{\theeqfloat}{\theequation}

\begin{document}

A standard equation
\begin{equation}
a+b=b+a
\end{equation}

\begin{eqfloat}[htp]
\begin{equation}
\partial v=\frac{\gamma -1}{\gamma^3*\beta^3}*\partial E
\end{equation}
\caption{Relative velocity spread calculated relativistically}
\label{eq:velocity_spread}
\end{eqfloat}`

See Equation~\eqref{eq:velocity_spread}.

\end{document}

I removed all the unneeded packages, you can add the ones you employ. But consider that a4wide has been deprecated for more than 20 years. Use geometry if you want to modify the page parameters.
I used newfloat instead of float, because it's better integrated with caption.

On the other hand, I don't think you really want floats, but just the ability to caption a set of equations.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% for the second set of equations
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Rot}{rot}
\newcommand\parder[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{captiondisplay}{m}
 {%
  $$\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}\noindent
 }
 {%
  \sffamily\sbox{0}{#1}%
  \ifdim\wd0<\dimeval{\textwidth-2\leftmargin}
    \begin{center}\usebox{0}\end{center}%
  \else
    \begin{quote}#1\end{quote}%
  \fi
  \end{minipage}$$
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}
a+b=b+a
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{captiondisplay}{Relative velocity spread calculated relativistically}
  \begin{equation}
  \partial v=\frac{\gamma -1}{\gamma^3*\beta^3}*\partial E
  \label{eq:velocity_spread}
  \end{equation}
\end{captiondisplay}
See Equation~\eqref{eq:velocity_spread}. \lipsum[4][1-4]
\begin{captiondisplay}{Maxwell's equation with some more words to make the caption
  long enough to split across lines}
  \begin{align}
  \label{eq:maxwell-A}
  \begin{split}
    \Rot\vec{E} &=-\frac{1}{c}\parder{\vec{B}}{t}, \\
    \Div\vec{B} &=0,
  \end{split}
  \\[2ex]
  \label{eq:maxwell-B}
  \begin{split}
    \Rot\vec{B} &=\frac{1}{c}\parder{\vec{E}}{t}+\frac{4\pi}{c}\,\vec{j}, \\
    \Div\vec{E} &=4\pi\rho_{\varepsilon }
  \end{split}
  \end{align}
\end{captiondisplay}
\lipsum[20][1-3]

\end{document}



You should IMHO move the \label into the equation environment. Otherwise it would still refer to the eqfloat counter instead of the equation counter.

Also note, that this example still writes a the eqfloat counter to the eqflts auxiliary file. So the "List of Eqflts" would show "1 Relative velocity spread …". Just add \listofeqfloat to the example to see it.

@cabohah Yes, I saw the problem. Solved by making \theeqfloat an alias to \theequation.

I want to say a late thanks to you. This pretty much nailed the problem :)
